# Should I use "for" or "of" after the word "test"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

I wan to say we tested (tried) iphone version #

Which one is correct?

> Our test of iphone version # shows that ...

Or,

> Our test for iphone version # shows that ...

Comment: Is [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/248787/115654) helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either could be used and would have a slightly different connotation.

In the example:

> "Our test **of** the phone...",

Using *of* implies that the test is a generic test which was tried on the phone

In the example:

> "Our test **for** the phone...",

Using *for* implies that the test was designed specifically for usage on the phone.