# "test for" vs. "test of"

Tags: meaning

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew_Dragon_In-Flight_Abort_Test)

> Dragon 2 In-Flight Abort Test (officially known as SpaceX In-Flight Abort Test and Crew Dragon Launch Escape Demonstration) was **a test of** the Crew Dragon abort system.

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20test%20of%2C%20a%20test%20for&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ca%20test%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20test%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20test%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20Test%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20Test%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ca%20test%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20test%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20test%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20Test%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20Test%20for%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Ca%20test%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20test%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20test%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20Test%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20Test%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ca%20test%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20test%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20test%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20Test%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20Test%20for%3B%2Cc0) shows that "a test for" is also a commonly used phrase.

[image]

> An attempt to generate **a test for** this fault condition may be made later in the process if the conditions are right

"a test of" seems to be part of validation, if the test is passed, the system could be considered solid and reliable.

"a test for" seems to be part of investigation which is usually for some expected failure or malfunction.

Is my understanding right?

---

This post is different from [Should I use "for" or "of" after the word "test"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/214524/115654), which just posts questions without any further investigation and their own understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is fairly good, but incomplete.

- "A test for iodine uses starch." This is not a test for a fault condition, but for the existence or absence of something, some condition.
- "A marathon is a test of endurance." Here, you could say that it is testing to failure, the breaking point.

Comment: Your answer is so helpful. Thank you. Would you please make up a situation where "A test of iodine" or "a test for endurance" would be used?

Comment: "A test of iodine's efficacy would be to apply it to the bacterial culture in vitro." "A test for endurance is the Cardiorespiratory Endurance test."